# Time series forecast with multiple time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Supposing that I have 1000 data of characteristics of a machine (Period = 1..1000), with 6 dependent variables (Pressure, Speed, Temperature, Sound, Noise, and Vibration). Most of these variables follow an exponential distribution. How do I get predictions for periods 1001 through 1100 based on this old data using R?

An example of the data is shown below. The behavior changes in certain periods of time due to machine failures, for example in Period 14. In this case, the values of Period 14 are equal to Period 1.

[image]

Comment: You might want to read [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/)

Comment: @phiver I read the book indicated. Thank you! I used the VAR method for forecasting, but the predictions were very bad. The method cannot predict the moments when the machine is reset and returns to its initial state. Any suggestion to deal with that?

Comment: What is the frequency of the data? how long are the breaks between machine failures and fixes, how long it takes to fix the machine and re-operate?